# Is there a keyboard shortcut to pin a tab?

Tags: safari, macos

In the Safari 9 for OS X El Capitan there is a new feature whereby you can pin a tab. As a result you will see a colored icon with the first letter of the website.

Now I wonder if there is a keyboard shortcut to do that automatically without me first right-click on that tab to pin it. When I go to **Window > Pin Tab** I see no shortcut. I know that this does not always mean that there is no keyboard shortcut for it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: With "command" do you mean a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: I do not know why I said command. Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not on El Capitan yet. But if there is a menu bar entry in Safari to create a pinned tab, you can assign a custom keyboard shortcut.

1. Go to **System Preferences > Keyboard**
2. Select the **Shortcuts** Tab
3. Select **App Shortcuts** at the bottom of the list
4. Create a new shortcut:

   - Application Safari
   - The title is the exact name of the menu bar entry
   - Choose a shortcut that you like

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I now have a shortcut for Pin Tab and Unpin Tab. Now when I pin a tab it will pin or unpin it depending on the current state of the tab window. Still wondering if there is a native shortcut for this.

Comment: Not sure. I've tried googling without success.

Answer (score 2):

#### Keyboard shortcut for both pinning *and* unpinning

If you keyboard shortcuts for pinning tabs and unpinning tabs are different, it will not work.

Specifically, once you pin a tab, you will not be able to unpin it using the unpin tab shortcut until you click the "Window" menu.

This is because the menu item in the "Window" menu is only changed from "Pin tab" to "Unpin tab" when you open it.

What’s the solution?

Set the same shortcut for both.

For example, you can set both shortcuts to <kbd>Cmd+Opt+P</kbd>.

[image]